# ViewPager fragments are lost when parent Fragment is hidden. How do I fix that?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment (ProfileFragment) which contains a ViewPager. Viewpager contains 2 fragments. When the ProfileFragment is first set up, it works fine. However, when you open other fragments then return to ProfileFragment, the fragments in ViewPager are gone. How do I make sure they stay? Here are my code:

**ProfileFragment:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new ProfileUserInfoFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ProfileUserInfoFragment();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Note: I saw some answers suggested using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(), but I can't use it, it says cannot resolve method.

Comment: Does the ProfileFragment extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment ? If it does you should be able to call getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Yes it extends support fragment.

Comment: There might be problems with my gradle libraries, which one do I need here?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

> ```
> adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
> pager.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

Comment: It says 'cannot resolve method getChildFragmentManager()'

Comment: There might be problems with my gradle libraries, which one do I need here?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

Comment: It seems nothing is wrong with libraries. I just cant use getChildFragmentManager method on my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your ProfileFragment should extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in order to use `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: @DogeDogeoglu can you also import import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager ? in ProfileFragment

Comment: I imported that too, but it didnt change anything.

Comment: There might be problems with my gradle libraries, which one do I need here?

Comment: You need the support library, but in you adapter you already use imports from the support library so I don't think that's the cause

Comment: So what is the issue here?

Comment: @DogeDogeoglu What version of the support library are you using ? Do you compile use compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1' ? And do you have import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; in your ProfileFragment, not just the adapter ?

Comment: When i try to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager to ProfileFragment it automatically deletes it. We might be onto something here.

Comment: @DogeDogeoglu change getFragmentManager() to getChildFragmentManager() first and then import the FragmentManager

Comment: It seems there is no method in that class. I checked the source. GetChildFragmentManager seems to be in native fragmentmanager class, but we are using supportfragmentmanager here.